# Applying islice to ijson, getting list of lists when applied?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to apply `islice` over a huge JSON file which contains around ~180k documents.

The file is, as an example:

```
[
  {"propertyA": "abc"},
  {"propertyB": "bcd"},
  ...
]
```

As of now I'm doing `islice(ijson.items(file, prefix=''), 10000)` and getting OOMs, and when checking what `ijson.items(file, prefix='')` returns for the first element doing `ijson.items(file, prefix='').__next__()`, the result is as follows:

```
[ {doc1}, {doc2}, {doc3}, ... ]
```

The json file I'm reading is not structured as list of lists, only a single list with the documents, why am I getting a list of lists with the first item being the whole content of the file? Shouldn't I be getting just `{doc1}` when asking for the `__next__()`? Am I using `ijson` erroneously that it's wrapping the file around yet another list?

Comment: Is your example correct with square brackets as outer brackets? AFAIK a json file should have curly outer brackets. If so, this might lead to weird outputs.

Comment: @OskarHofmann yes, the file itself is like a list of documents.

Comment: Have you checked similar questions, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47780053/how-to-use-ijson-other-to-parse-this-large-json-file or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64270230/using-ijson-parse-and-ijson-items-to-load-a-big-json-file-why-does-this-wo ?

Comment: The first and only element in your json as desribed in the example is a list of objects. So the first item you get is this list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When parsing items inside an array, the prefix for the array should be the word "item".

In other words, instead of an empty prefix, which will try to parse the top level object, you should call it this way:  `ijson.items(file, prefix='item')`, then, each item of this iterable will be one element of the top level array in the file.

It is in the project's README docs, but worded in a way that is a bit hard to follow, because we tend not to believe that "a literal `item` part" really means using the `item` name - so, I've even tried it locally to assert it is so. https://github.com/ICRAR/ijson?tab=readme-ov-file#prefix

```
In [41]: import io, json, ijson

In [42]: file = io.StringIO(json.dumps([{'propertyA': 'abc'}, {'propertyB': 'bcd'},]))

In [43]: file.seek(0)
Out[43]: 0

In [44]: iterator = ijson.items(file, "item")

In [45]: next(iterator)
Out[45]: {'propertyA': 'abc'}

In [46]: next(iterator)
Out[46]: {'propertyB': 'bcd'}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That clears a lot, however I just tried and I'm getting an incomplete JSON and also an exception after processing the first element, the real objects are bigger than those in the sample I mentioned and may be processing the file from S3 iteratively, since this is all in a huge single line...